# mysql error for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.15:

Tags: mysql, perl

i am using mysql for orthomcl software. when i use the command

`orthomclLoadBlast my_orthomcl/orthomcl.config my_orthomcl/similarSequence.txt`

it gives this error

```
Can't load '/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230,  line 5. at /storage/home/cdac/OrthoMCL/orthomclSoftwarev2.0.8/bin/../lib/perl/OrthoMCLEngine/Main/Base.pm line48
Compilation failed in require at /storage/home/cdac/OrthoMCL/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.8/bin/../lib/perl/OrthoMCLEngine/Main/Base.pm line 48, <F> line 5.
```

How to solve this problem ??

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried to install dynaloader, right?

Comment: How did you install DBD::mysql? -- Ignore the comment above, Dynaloader is part of Perl.

Comment: no sir i was not trying to install dynaloader @ jamie taylor

Comment: sir i installed mysql using yum install mysql-server

Comment: Have you also installed the mysql client? yum install mysql

Comment: is there any solution for this problem? I am experiencing the same

Answer (score 0):

You could install a local perl in your home and you could leave vendor perl untouched.

You could use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) or [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/local-lib-1.008010/lib/local/lib.pm) to maintain an up to date perl version without modifying the system installed perl.

Comment: is it the solution of this problem ??